# How to allow my team members to access my AWS mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

So I created a RDS with AWS, I shared the endpoint and port number with my team, but when they try to log onto my server they get the following:

[image: error my teammates get]

Why can't they log in, but I can from my mySQL workbench? I logged in, created a schema, and did some insert/delete operations to test everything out. But they can't log in.

Also, they want the schema code (which I created using forward engineering) but I forgot to copy it. Is there any way to access it from mySQL workbench? The code that is created from forward engineering?

Comment: Are your team members attempting to access from the same network? When it fails, does it give the error immediately, or does it take some time before failing? (A time delay indicates no network access, whereas an immediate error indicates rejected access.)

Comment: The screenshot shows that they are connecting as user `root`. Is that the same username you are using?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes I am using root as well. But I think I was logged off. I'm asking them right now if they were denied immediately. I should get a response soon, but if not, would you mind if I tag your name again tomorrow with a response?

Comment: They are not in the same location as you? Are you accessing via a different network? You should check the Security Group associated with the Amazon RDS instance to determine whether it is restricting to certain IP addresses only.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html *By default, network access is disabled for a DB instance. You can specify rules in a security group that allow access from an IP address range, port, or EC2 security group. Once ingress rules are configured, the same rules apply to all DB instances that are associated with that security group. You can specify up to 20 rules in a security group.*

You need to adjust your RDS security group to allow access from your team's IP address to the port 3306